# Why doesn't the fat in pemmican mold?

Tags: drying

I've learned today that pemmican is pulverized dried meat mixed with fat. But why doesn't the fat develop mold? I have read fats develop mold easily.

Comment: Does your cooking oil (another kind of fat) get moldy?

Comment: @Sneftel Good question, I've never done Pemmican and I think it's mixed with tallow (white fat from the cooking of meat).  I mean cooking oil doesn't mold but do you mix cooking oil with the dried meat to make Pemmican?

Comment: Do you mean it gets moldy?  Or that it's able to be shaped in a mold?

Comment: @Quinto: Fat not oil gets moldy easily, right? It doesn't conserve.

Comment: @Gigamegs The only thing that distinguishes oils and fats is whether they're liquid at room temperature.

Comment: @Sneftel But it doesn't answer the question. Pemmican is made with fat. And fat gets moldy easily, right? Oil doesn't mold, I know, but I am a terrible cook.

Comment: Neither fat nor oil gets moldy easily. Common bread and vegetable molds prefer to metabolize carbohydrates.

Comment: @Sneftel: It depends what's easily. I had fat (tallow) in my fridge for some time and it develop mold. It was a couple of month. Maybe it was dirty (but it was also in my fridge)? And I also read if you want to make dried meat you need to cut the fat because this fat develop mold!? I am confused!

Comment: Fat does not get moldy easily.  Quite the opposite.  In fact, before glass jars, people frequently used a layer of fat on top of other foods to *preserve* it: https://moorlandseater.com/homemade-potted-beef/

Comment: If you had tallow in the fridge that went mouldy, it was more probably because of cross-contamination than anything else. It's like finding mould on butter - it's the toast crumbs that go mouldy, not the butter.

Comment: If it's clean saturated fat it isn't going to mold. They sell lard unrefrigerated on the shelves at the supermarket. The stuff probably lasts for years.

Answer (score 5):

Mold spores are everywhere, but they need certain conditions in order to grow.  Food preservation and storage steps protect against spoilage.  Mold growth is one (of many) potentials for spoilage (although in some instances, cheese for example, it is desirable).  Fat doesn't necessarily encourage mold growth any more than other products.  The conditions that mold spores need to grow are (a) water, (b) food in the form of dead or decaying matter, (c) air, and (d) temperature (70F or 20C is ideal).  In the case of pemmican, the water activity of the product is very low, as it is made mostly from dried meat and fat.  During the time that it was used and popular, it was probably protected from the air as much as was reasonable, and it was used and stored (mostly) in cool temperatures.  None of that guarantees that it will not, or never did mold.  I can imagine an early Native American, or North American explorer reaching into a leather saddle bag after the spring rains and pulling out some moldy pemmican.  In that scenario, the conditions could be perfect for mold growth.  So, to directly answer your question, it's not the fat or the pemmican.  Mold can grow on anything that supports its growth if the conditions are right.

Comment: Thanks, but I also read if you want to make dried meat you need to cut the fat because this fat develop mold but Pemmican is mixed with fat. I am confused.

Comment: Fat is removed when drying meat because it becomes rancid very easily.  It's not about mold development. Pemmican was typically made with rendered fat, which probably increased the shelf life.

Comment: You mean rendered fat=tallow? I had tallow but it had not last long in my fridge. Only a few of months: this  https://www.milkwood.net/2015/11/06/how-to-render-animal-fat-making-lard-and-tallow/. However I had it in an open box.

Comment: Tallow is one example.  Yes, it can mold, provided the conditions are right, as described above.

Comment: So tallow doesn't develop rancid like fat (from the meat)?

Comment: It certainly can.  It depends on the storage conditions.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of fat. Rendered Suet, or the organ fat, is what gives pemmican its longevity. You can make it with other fats and it may taste better, but it won’t last as long. Dry the meat then soak it in the Tallow. The dried meat absorbs the tallow which prevents moisture from being absorbed into the meat.